# How to obtain the PR title and store it in a variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to be able to get the PR message and store it as a variable in Azure Devops so I can change the title to have `** SKIP TEST **` and scan for that in the pipeline rather than going through variables UI manually.

I think I'd just need to perform some sort of REST API call since I already have the PR ID and other identifying information.  Then use the facility that reads the output and stores the value to a variable.

Comment: whats a PR message?

Comment: Hi, i posted an answer below, is it what you want? Can you follow the steps get PR message expected? If so, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Or if you got any problem about the solution, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this on YAML pipelines (rather than Classic)

```yaml
steps:
  - bash: |
      PR_TITLE="$(curl --silent -u azdo:$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN \
       $(System.CollectionUri)_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)?api-version=5.1 \
       | jq -r .title)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Pr.Title]$PR_TITLE"
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    displayName: Extract pull request title
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))

  - bash: |
      echo "running test"
    displayName: Run test
    condition: and(succeeded(), not(startsWith(variables['Pr.Title'], '**SKIPTEST**')))
```

Here is an example with everything in one line, but I prefer the above one as it is easier for someone new to read it

```yaml
steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Pr.Title]"$(curl --silent -u azdo:$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN $(System.CollectionUri)_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)?api-version=5.1 | jq -r .title)
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    displayName: Extract pull request title
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))

  - bash: |
      echo "running test"
    displayName: Run test
    condition: and(succeeded(), not(startsWith(variables['Pr.Title'], '**SKIPTEST**')))
```

### Labels

In addition if you prefer "labels" rather than changing the title (I prefer the title myself because it is clearly visible everywhere) the labels can be extracted using the following script

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    LABELS=$(curl --silent -u azdo:$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN $(System.CollectionUri)_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/labels?api-version=5.1-preview.1 | jq .value[].name)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Pr.Labels]$LABELS"
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: Get Pull Request Labels
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
- bash: |
    echo "running test"
  displayName: Run test
  condition: and(succeeded(), not(contains(variables['Pr.Labels'], '"skip-test"')))
```

Note I didn't use `-r` on the JQ so that the values are quoted.  This allows a more explicit check for the string rather than matching the label that may contain the text as a sub-string.

Comment: Hi Archimedes, I have tried your first solution. But for System.PullRequest.PullRequestID, I get command not found in the pipeline instead of PR ID. I am trying to fetch the PR ID after the PR is completed and the pipeline is not dependent on any other pipeline. Hosted VM is ubuntu. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

> I think I'd just need to perform some sort of REST API call since I already have the PR ID and other identifying information.

Since you have the PR ID already, i suggest [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Use this api:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.1`

As you can see in the doc [response sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples), there is `title`.

```
  ...
  "creationDate": "2016-11-01T16:30:31.6655471Z",
  "title": "A new feature",
  "description": "Adding a new feature",
  ...
```

> store it in a variable

As for how to store it in a variable, i suggest that you can create a variable and then update it.

Please refer to below demo using powershell task to call Rest Api and update the variable value and then use it in the next cmd task:

Variable:

[image]

Powershell task:

[image]

Powershell script:

```
$personalToken="******************************"
$token=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header=@{authorization="Basic $token"}
$projectUrl ="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests/{PRid}?api-version=5.1"
$content=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectUrl -Method GET -contentType "application/json" -Headers $header
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myTitle;]$content"
```

CMD task:

[image]

CMD result:

[image]