# Enforcing Pull Requests title

Tags: azure-devops

I used some GitHub gates for enforcing Pull Requests title by rules. But I didn't find any way to do it on Azure DevOps (the code is hosted on Azure DevOps Repo).

How can I create a PR gate that enforces the Pull Requests title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a small pipeline with a powershell task which examines the pull request title and checks if it is valid.

Then, you configure your master branch to include that pipeline as part of the [Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) policy; the pipeline will automatically get run, and automatically gate the PR.

Note; you will have to [call the Azure Devops REST API to get hold of the PR name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761324/174843), because while the pull request ID is automatically supplied in the [pre-defined system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services), the pull request name is not.

Comment: Thank you! "small pipeline with a powershell task which examines the pull request title and checks if it is valid." can you please provide an example or link to documentation of how to do that?

Comment: if ($pipelineName -notmatch $regex) {Write-Error "Invalid PR name"; throw; }

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 5):

I implemented the very good suggestion by [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70288545/1198379). First I created a simple powershell script (`validate_conventional_commit.ps1`) to validate if a string complies with the Regex I want to match it with. In this case, I want PR titles to comply with [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0).

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$CommitMessage
)

$Regex="^(fix|feat):"

if ($CommitMessage -match $Regex) {
  Write-Host "The commit message complies with conventional commits."
}
else {
  Throw "Error : Invalid commit message!"
}
```

Then I created a pipeline to examine the PR title and check if it is valid.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
  - bash: |
      pr_title="$(curl --silent -u azdo:$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN \
       $(System.CollectionUri)_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)?api-version=5.1 \
       | jq -r .title)"

      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pr_title;]'$pr_title'"
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    displayName: Extract pull request title

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Validate the PR title, which will be used as the commit message when merging to the target branch'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: 'validate_conventional_commit.ps1'
      arguments: '$(pr_title)'
      failOnStderr: true
```

And lastly, I created a [PR trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) via a Build Validation branch policy, which will trigger the pipeline when a PR is created against the target branch.